# Why do I get this warning when replacing pattern with list element?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, replacement, warning-messages

The input `x^2 + x^3 /. x^i_ -> i`
yields:

> 5

The input

```
u = {1, 2, 3}
x^2 + x^3 /. x^i_ -> u[[i]]
```

still yields the same output, but this time I get the following warning:

> Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.

What is the reason behind this warning? And what would be an appropriate way of replacing a pattern with a list element, where the pattern specifies the index of the list element?

Comment: Use RuleDelayed (:>) instead of Rule (->)

Comment: If for whatever reason you want to use ->, you can try `Activate[x^2 + x^3 /. x^i_ -> Inactive[u[[i]]]]`

Comment: The problem is that `u[[i]]` is evaluated before the rule is formed.  Since `i` does not have a value at this point, Mathematica warns that it cannot take the `i`th part of `u`.  This problem is avoided if you use `RuleDelayed` as @CarlWoll suggested.